# Ways to give AWS S3A credentials

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to use Amazon's S3 as a DR backup for my data through Hadoop distcp. I have some big files, so I need to use S3A. This command works:

```
hadoop distcp <source> s3a://<ID>:<KEY>@bucket/
```

I want to script this command and would prefer not putting the ID and KEY into the URL. Is there another way to specify them, e.g., in the Hadoop configuration files or environment variables?

Answering my own question. Every time I tried to remove the ID and KEY to a configuration XML file or to JVM variables it failed. I finally realized it was because I was keeping the '@' symbol when it needed to be removed too:

Works:
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key= -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=  s3a:///
Doesn't work:
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key= -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=  s3a://@/

If fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key are set in a Hadoop configuration file, e.g. hdfs-site.xml, this works:
hadoop distcp  s3a:///
But this doesn't work:
hadoop distcp  s3a://@/

If fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key are set in an alternative configuration file, this works:
hadoop distcp -conf   s3a:///
But this doesn't work:
hadoop distcp -conf   s3a://@/

Comment: Have you looked at using Roles? This is usually the recommended way to pass credentials in AWS. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles-calling.html)

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/59161/using-hadoop-credential-api-to-store-aws-secrets.html